# Input and output file formats for Adobe Access packager

Tags: flash, air, adobe, flash-media-server

I am doing some research on the Adobe Access packager, and from all of my reading of the literature it seems Adobe Access packager only accepts F4V and FLV input types, and only spits out the same as output types.

I am looking to input and output mp4 format (H.264 codec). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some more research and reaching out to Adobe, I found that yes, mp4 is supported, since F4V is basically an mp4.